# where to check for the error and how

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have a code design question.
My question is where should I place my user error handling code and what method should I use.

The situation is this, my user should provide a file name to a function, this function then tries to open the file and manipulate it. Should the file not exist I would like to notify the user and try again with a newly inputted file name. As I understand std exception handling is not a suitable solution for this case.
Now I believe I have a couple of options; check the file exists before calling the function,
check whether it exists within the function and return a true false to indicate whether it was successful, or check whether it exists within the file if not calling a function which prints the message and allows the name to be changed before returning to the original function.

Which of these methods is preferred and why, is there a better alternative/lib functionality I should be using.

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is inconsequential but I like to try and get these things right.

Comment: Why do you think exception handling is not suitable?

Comment: When you say the user provides a file name to the function, do you mean that the file name is an *argument* to the function, or that the function, once running, *asks for and accepts* the file name?

Comment: I thought std exception handling was not meant for runtime errors such as user input. File name is an argument that is fetched from the user elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @Useless: exceptions are generally frown upon when validating user input.

Comment: Any links to the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @Useless: no particular link, the reasoning is usually that exceptions should be reserved for exceptional situations and by definition the "adapter" zones (at the boundary of the applications) are brittle and thus it is *expected* for malformed input to happen, there is nothing exceptional there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need specific input for a function, you should always check the arguments inside of the function if unexpected arguments will result in unexpected behavior, except your trying to build a high performance application. That's what `std::invalid_argument` in `<stdexcept>` is for.

Of course you should always try to ensure that the arguments you provide to your procedures are correct. But it doesn't harm you if your function can tell you that something is currently going wrong. Since your program can't read `std::cout` you have to stick to exceptions or return error codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

void myFunction(const std::string& inputFileName){
    std::ifstream myFile(inputFileName.c_str());
    if(!myFile.good())
        throw std::invalid_argument("The file does not exist!\n");
    /* other operations */
}

int main(){
    std::string userInput;

    std::cin >> userInput;
    while(userInput != "quit"){
        try{
            myFunction(userInput);
        }catch(const std::invalid_argument& e){
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        std::cin >> userInput;
    }
    return 0;    
}
/* this code is just a small example and could be improved */
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you should try to open the file once you've got the filename, and loop if that fails.  And the function should take an `std::istream&`, and not the filename.  At least in the small scenario you show.  Alternatively, the function can take the filename, and return an error code indicating whether it was unable to open the file or not.  And there are cases (not very frequent, but they do exist) where the alternatives to using an exception have even more disadvantages, so the exception would be the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't disregard exceptions that easily and say that they are not suitable. It just depends on the overall design - e.g. whether your client has exception handling enabled or not. You can build your exception class hierarchy and have let's say `CFileException` (inherited from `std::exception`) and then `CFileNotFoundException`, `CFileAccessDeniedException`...etc....inherited from it. If your client is happy to handle this type of exceptions - use them! You can pass more information about the error within the exception object than in the error code plus your client can decide where will that exception be handled.

The other solution is to return different error codes for different errors. Don't just return `true`/`false` - it will not give much information to the client (why did function fail). Client will need to test error code and produce message (error description, error cause) to the user accordingly. If you use exception instead, that message could be created in the function that failed - which is the context that contains more information about the error and its nature and so can create more descriptive message.

Regarding the breaking your function into smaller ones: you said "*function then tries to open the file and manipulate it*" so it would be worth having two separate functions - one which opens file and another which process it. The same rules for exception/errors apply - if opening file fails, exception will be thrown and the second would not be entered.